# EmEditor script: extend the selection range to include multiple separate words?

Tags: javascript, macros, emeditor

I want to extract all the misspelled words in Emeditor. As in the script below, I would first mark all the misspelled work with a special string "@@@" which is then used for extrating the words.

I wonder whether it's possible to directly extend the selection range to include multiple separate words. If this is possible to the string "@@@" would be unnecessary. Thank you!

```
    document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);

    while (true) {

    var xPos = document.selection.GetActivePointX(eePosView)
    var yPos = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosView)

    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4554);  // Next Misspelling

    var xPos2 = document.selection.GetActivePointX(eePosView)
    var yPos2 = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosView)

    if (xPos === xPos2 && yPos === yPos2) break

    document.selection.text = "@@@"
    }

    document.selection.Find("@@@[[:word:]]+", eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindExtract | eeFindMatchedOnly, eeExFindSeparateCRLF | eeExFindRegexOnigmo)
    document.selection.Replace("@@@", "", eeReplaceAll, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't easy to extend the selection range to include multiple separate words, but I rewrote your macro by selecting misspelled words and appending them to a string variable (`s`).

```
Redraw = false;
var s = "";
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
while (true) {
    var xPos = document.selection.GetActivePointX(eePosView);
    var yPos = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosView);

    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4554);  // Next Misspelling

    var xPos2 = document.selection.GetActivePointX(eePosView);
    var yPos2 = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosView);

    if (xPos === xPos2 && yPos === yPos2) break;

    document.selection.SelectWord();
    s += document.selection.Text + "\r\n";
}

editor.NewFile();
document.selection.Text = s;
```

Comment: Hi Mr. @Yutaka   Thank you for your codes!

Comment: Hi Mr. @Yutaka, sorry for another trivial question. I have a lot of buttons on the Macro toolbar. Is it possible to add separators to the Macro toolbar? Thank you!

Comment: You can create a new `Basic` toolbar, and add some of your favorite macros and separators. Next time, please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm doing now.